Unity 6 - can't set the sprite of an UI image
I've always been able to drag and drop a sprite into the inspector, setting the sprite of a UI image to the sprite. But I can't this time, even though the sprite is set as Sprite(2D and UI). What's going on here?
I'm using the new Unity 6

Set the sprite mode to Single(it was multiple)

Try changing Sprite Mode to multiple and select your sprite in sprite editor mode then apply it. You'll see another sprite in your main sprite that one you crop. Try drag that one.

Actually I fixed it I had to set it to Single(it was multiple)
